# i want to remove the duplicate sub integer arraylist from an integer arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

you are given an nested array list such as :
list = [[-1,2,1],[-2,-2,4],[-1,2,-1],[-1,-2,3],[-1,2,-1]]

i want to have an output like this :
[[-1,2,1],[-2,-2,4],[-1,-2,3]]

but its not likely to come with the code i am using...

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
if(list.get(i).eqauls(list.get(j)))
 {
 list.remove(list.get(j));
  }
  }
  }
 System.out.println(list);
```

i have done like this but its not taking and duplicates are still there
so i have done in another way something like this...

```
List<List<Integer>> list2=  new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
if(!list.get(i).eqauls(list.get(j)))
 {
 List<Integer> p= new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(int m=0;m<list.size();m++){
 for(int n=0;n<list.get(i).size();n++){
 p.add(list.get(i).get(m));
 list2.add(p);
 }
 }
 }
System.out.println(list2);
```

Output: Run time error
What should i do in this case....only using array list data structures only...

Comment: Do you consider `[-1,2,1]` and `[-1,2,-1]`. Just to be clear, on what basis are these 2 considered same?

Comment: Your j upper bound seems to be wrong

Comment: You wrote in your question: _Output: Run time error_ Maybe you can [edit] your question and post the actual error message you are seeing along with the stack trace? My guess it's because of this line of your code: `List<List<Integer>> list2=  new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();` I don't see where you are populating `list2`. You are creating an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

#### Strategy

We can build a tree data structure, the paths of which are exactly the unique sub-lists contained within your master list. Once the tree is built, we can iterate over it, e.g. with a recursive algorithm, and re-build a master list of lists, without any duplicates.

#### Code

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListUnduper{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Tree root = new Tree();
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> first = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        first.add(1); first.add(2);
        List<Integer> second = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        //Add more lists here if you like
        list.add(first); list.add(second);
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
          List<Integer> inner = list.get(i);
          Tree current = root;
          for(int j=i+1;j<inner.size();j++){
            int nextElement = inner.get(j);        
            if(!current.children.containsKey(nextElement)){
              current.children.put(nextElement, new Tree());
            }
            current = current.children.get(nextElement);
           }
        }

        List<List<Integer>> master = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> emptyPrefix = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        addAllToList(emptyPrefix, master, root);    

        //master now should contain all non-dupes 
     }

    static void addAllToList(List<Integer> prefix, List<List<Integer>> master, Tree tree){
      for(Map.Entry<Integer,Tree> entry : tree.children.entrySet()){
        Tree nextTree = entry.getValue();  
        //I believe this makes a deep copy
        List<Integer> nextPrefix = new ArrayList<>(prefix);
        nextPrefix.add(entry.getKey());
        if(nextTree.children.isEmpty()){
          master.add(nextPrefix);
        }
        else{
          addAllToList(nextPrefix, master, tree);
        }
      }
    }
}

class Tree{
  HashMap<Integer, Tree> children = new HashMap<Integer, Tree>();
}
```

Warning: using recursion may result in Stackoverflow errors if your lists are large. In that case, it's advisable to switch to using a while loop, but the algorithm will likely be more complicated to code in that case.

#### Note on Order of Elements

As [this alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61950332/5134722) points out, the original order of lists within the master list may be important. The above solution does not guarantee preserving such an order.

Comment: Your code contains several issues. For instance, you are using raw types and you're using a primitive type as a type argument (which doesn't compile).

Comment: @MCEmperor V. true. Lazy algo sketch replaced with working code

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is probably a school assignment designed to get you to practice using lists and iterators and the `equals()` method,  maybe even [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). And I'm quite sure that you have not yet learned about the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) but since your code uses `List`, that means you have learned about the [collections framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) so I don't need to explain to you what a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is. In any case, your task can be accomplished quite easily using the *stream API* and the *collections framework* as shown in the below code. (Note that the below code uses methods introduced in Java 9.)

```java
/* Required imports
 * 
 * import java.util.List;
 * import java.util.Set;
 * import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 */
List<List<Integer>> list2 = List.of(List.of(-1,2,1),
                                    List.of(-2,-2,4),
                                    List.of(-1,2,-1),
                                    List.of(-1,-2,3),
                                    List.of(-1,2,-1));
Set<List<Integer>> noDups = list2.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(noDups);
```

Running the above code produces the following output.
(Note that iterating a `Set` does not guarantee any special ordering.)

```
[[-2, -2, 4], [-1, -2, 3], [-1, 2, -1], [-1, 2, 1]]
```

Refer to method [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) of interface `java.util.List`

### EDIT

Due to [Colm Bhandal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5134722/colm-bhandal)'s comment, and taking inspiration from *artmmslv*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949522/i-want-to-remove-the-duplicate-sub-integer-arraylist-from-an-integer-arraylist-i/61949596#61949596), if the order is important, then the below code, which is slightly modified from the above code, will maintain the order.

```java
List<List<Integer>> list2 = List.of(List.of(-1,2,1),
                                    List.of(-2,-2,4),
                                    List.of(-1,2,-1),
                                    List.of(-1,-2,3),
                                    List.of(-1,2,-1));
Set<List<Integer>> noDups = list2.stream()
                                 .collect(LinkedHashSet::new,
                                          LinkedHashSet::add,
                                          LinkedHashSet::addAll);
System.out.println(noDups);
```

The output from this code is:

```
[[-1, 2, 1], [-2, -2, 4], [-1, 2, -1], [-1, -2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your sub-arrays to [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

This collection stores objects in order of addition (and does not store equal objects)

Comment: Succinct, and answers the question, but I think you should add some code demonstrating how to accomplish your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code by yourself, no magic function to do for you.

You can see the sample code below.

```js
const input = [[-1,2,1],[-2,-2,4],[-1,2,-1],[-1,-2,3],[-1,2,-1]]

const removeDuplicate = list => {
  const set = new Set()
  for (const item of list) {
     set.add(item.join('|'))
  }
  const result = Array.from(set).map(strItem => {
    const resultItem = strItem.split('|').map(item => parseInt(item))
    return resultItem
  })
  return result
}

const result = removeDuplicate(input)

console.log(result)
```